# estimates for least squares vs estimates for ridge

Tags: self-study, statistical-learning

The coefficient estimates for RSS is given $\hat{\beta} = (\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{Y}$, while for ridge regression, $\hat{\beta}^\text{ridge} = (\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X} + \lambda \mathbf{I})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{Y}$.

In Elements of Statistical Learning, p64, there is a claim at the end of the paragraph that for the case of orthogonal inputs, $\hat{\beta}^\text{ridge} = \dfrac{\hat{\beta}}{1+\lambda}$.

I am not sure how this result is proved, and what is the advantage of using this form?

Answer (score 3):

When the input matrix is orthogonal $X^{T}X = I$ so $\hat{\beta} = X^{T}Y$. Plug these facts in and you get the answer. The orthogonal case is amenable to analysis and provides insights into what one should expect. In fact, the predecessor of the LASSO is the soft thresholding operator, which was derived for the orthogonal matrix case by Donoho and Johnstone